# Save contentEditable to localStorage on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a table that contains content from an array of objects.

```
//starts table
    let myTable = "<table class=\"fl-table\"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Power</th><th>From</th><th>Action</th></tr>";
    //loops through data
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        //adds new row, starts first column
        myTable += "<tr><td contentEditable>";
        //adds name
        myTable += data[i].name;
        //closes first column, adds second
        myTable += "</td><td contentEditable>";
        //adds power
        myTable += data[i].power;
        //closes second column, adds third
        myTable += "</td><td contentEditable>";
        //adds fromCanon
        myTable += data[i].fromCanon;
        //closes third column, adds fourth
        myTable += "</td><td>";
        //adds deletion button
        myTable += "<button class=\"deleteRowBtn\" onclick='deleteRow(";
        myTable += i;
        myTable += ")'>Delete</button>"
        //adds modify button
        myTable += "<button class=\"editRowBtn\" onclick='editRow(";
        myTable += i;
        myTable += ")'>Save Edit</button>"
        //closes column and row
        myTable += "</td></tr>";
    }
```

However, now that I have this table, I would like users to be able to actually save whatever edits they make by clicking the edit button at the right end of each row. I've been able to allow deletion of rows like so:

```
function deleteRow(rowNum){
    allWorm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allWorm"));
    allWorm.splice(rowNum, 1);
    allWorm_serialized = JSON.stringify(allWorm);
    localStorage.setItem("allWorm", allWorm_serialized);
    writeData();
}
```

But how would I create a similar function for editRow that, instead of just deleting the row, commits whatever they change by editing the table to localStorage?

The data looks like this, as a sample:

```
var allWorm = [
        {
            "name": "Null",
            "power": "Create an artificial cluster. Everyone added to this cluster has their parahuman abilities shared, but with a decrease in the power of each new ability.",
            "fromCanon": "Null"
        },
        {
            "name": "One",
            "power": "Thinker ability that allows for quick and efficient brainwashing given sufficient control over the victim's environment.",
            "fromCanon": "One"
        },
        {
            "name": "Two",
            "power": "Magnify other powers in close proximity.",
            "fromCanon": "Two"
        },
        {
            "name": "Four",
            "power": "Limited flight. Can hover between five and ten feet from the ground with a top speed of fifty to sixty miles per hour.",
            "fromCanon": "Four"
        },
        {
            "name": "Nine",
            "power": "Can push and pull on metals within a short range, accelerating both self and object away from or towards each other.",
            "fromCanon": "Nine"
        },
        {
            "name": "Thirteen",
            "power": "Forcefield creation.",
            "fromCanon": "Thirteen"
        }
]
```

Comment: Where is your data?

Comment: The data looks like this, as a sample (edited post to include)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick. Tried it on my local.

```
function editRow(rowNum){
  allWorm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allWorm"));
   //because the table has a header, add 1 for the headers index
  var tds = document.querySelectorAll("tr")[rowNum + 1].childNodes;
  allWorm[rowNum].name = tds[0].textContent;
  allWorm[rowNum].power = tds[1].textContent;
  allWorm[rowNum].from = tds[2].textContent;
  allWorm_serialized = JSON.stringify(allWorm);
  localStorage.setItem("allWorm", allWorm_serialized);
}
```

```js
var allWorm = [{
    "name": "Null",
    "power": "Create an artificial cluster. Everyone added to this cluster has their parahuman abilities shared, but with a decrease in the power of each new ability.",
    "fromCanon": "Null"
  },
  {
    "name": "One",
    "power": "Thinker ability that allows for quick and efficient brainwashing given sufficient control over the victim's environment.",
    "fromCanon": "One"
  },
  {
    "name": "Two",
    "power": "Magnify other powers in close proximity.",
    "fromCanon": "Two"
  },
  {
    "name": "Four",
    "power": "Limited flight. Can hover between five and ten feet from the ground with a top speed of fifty to sixty miles per hour.",
    "fromCanon": "Four"
  },
  {
    "name": "Nine",
    "power": "Can push and pull on metals within a short range, accelerating both self and object away from or towards each other.",
    "fromCanon": "Nine"
  },
  {
    "name": "Thirteen",
    "power": "Forcefield creation.",
    "fromCanon": "Thirteen"
  }
]
localStorage.setItem("allWorm", JSON.stringify(allWorm));


let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allWorm"));

let myTable = "<table class=\"fl-table\"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Power</th><th>From</th><th>Action</th></tr>";
//loops through data
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  //adds new row, starts first column
  myTable += "<tr><td contentEditable>";
  //adds name
  myTable += data[i].name;
  //closes first column, adds second
  myTable += "</td><td contentEditable>";
  //adds power
  myTable += data[i].power;
  //closes second column, adds third
  myTable += "</td><td contentEditable>";
  //adds fromCanon
  myTable += data[i].fromCanon;
  //closes third column, adds fourth
  myTable += "</td><td>";
  //adds deletion button
  myTable += "<button class=\"deleteRowBtn\" onclick='deleteRow(";
  myTable += i;
  myTable += ")'>Delete</button>"
  //adds modify button
  myTable += "<button class=\"editRowBtn\" onclick='editRow(";
  myTable += i;
  myTable += ")'>Save Edit</button>"
  //closes column and row
  myTable += "</td></tr>";
}


function deleteRow(rowNum) {
  allWorm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allWorm"));
  allWorm.splice(rowNum, 1);
  allWorm_serialized = JSON.stringify(allWorm);
  localStorage.setItem("allWorm", allWorm_serialized);
  // writeData();
}

function editRow(rowNum) {
  allWorm = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allWorm"));
  //because the table has a header
  var tds = document.querySelectorAll("tr")[rowNum + 1].childNodes;
  allWorm[rowNum].name = tds[0].textContent;
  allWorm[rowNum].power = tds[1].textContent;
  allWorm[rowNum].from = tds[2].textContent;
  allWorm_serialized = JSON.stringify(allWorm);
  localStorage.setItem("allWorm", allWorm_serialized);
}

document.body.innerHTML = myTable;
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Do remove the whole `var allWorm =[...data]` and the succeeding `localStorage.setItem("allWorm", JSON.stringify(allWorm));` line once its initially loaded, otherwise the local would be overwritten.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I tested it out and it worked just as expected. :)

Comment: Thanks for telling me that was an option, SafeScript had that hidden.